# Azure Application Gateway - check health on subset of backend nodes

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-gateway, azure-vm-scale-set, health-check

I have a service fabric cluster that hosts some number of identical applications. The application has two main components - a stateless service that hosts web api (it listens on unique port number) and an actor service.

In front of it there is an application gateway instance with multisite listeners to reach proper application instance based on the url. The scale set for the service faberic cluster is set as backend pool for the application gateway.

For each application I have separate http settings with a unique backend port to reach. One of the configuration options for a listener is a health probe that check the web api health, by default on each backend node.

There is no problem when the api is deployed on each node on the backend, but when the api is deployed only on subset of nodes, for the nodes without it the health probe reports this app as unhealthy.

Is there a supported way to configure the application gateway health probe to check health only on a subset of backend nodes. For apps running on a service fabric cluster like in my case it will be strongly desired.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use a reverse proxy on the cluster for this. You can use the [built-in reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy#reaching-microservices-from-outside-the-cluster), or [Traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/configuration/backends/servicefabric/) for this.
This ensures that all incoming traffic is routed to the services.

It does introduce an additional network hop, so there is a performance impact.

Comment: Hi, I have an AKS cluster  that  uses Traefik ingress. Now I want to set up Azure WAF with Application Gateway. I've started to setup Azure Application Gateway. I was wondering if you can give me some info about how the connection between Traefik and Application Gateway would be? I couldn't find some useful info in google so far.